# Two click for dispatch action Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button, redux

I use REDUX in my REACTJS application. I want to retrieve the button ID after clicking the button and send it to my store. It's only works after the second click. Can you help me ? My code:

My function :

```js
gotoidee (e)  {
let test= this.state.data[e.target.id];
console.log("test" +test.titre);
    
const action = { type: "SAVE_IDEE_ID", value:this.state.data[e.target.id]};
this.props.dispatch(action);
console.log(this.props.ideeId.titre);
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {

ideeId: state.saveIdee.ideeId
}
  }
  
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(liste_idee)
```

My reducer :

```js
const initialState = { ideeId: [] }

function saveIdee  (state = initialState, action) {
  let nextState
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SAVE_IDEE_ID':
      nextState = {
        ...state,
        ideeId: action.value
    }
    return nextState

  default:
    return state
  }
}

export default saveIdee
```

My button :

```js
 <Button type="submit" id={ideeId} onClick={this.gotoidee}>Marche</Button>
```

Comment: Please try to include more code, it's hard to tell why is it not updated. How do you bind the action handler to your button? How do you connect your component to the reducer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
gotoidee (e)  {
  // check here if the click is happening by putting a console here
  let test= this.state.data[e.target.id];
  console.log("test" +test);
  const action = { type: "SAVE_IDEE_ID", value:test};
  this.props.dispatch(action);
}

render(){
 console.log(this.props.ideeId); // check the updated value
}
```